# Where is extra encoded query coming from and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I've the following in a SI

```
var serviceAsset=new GlideRecord('u_service_asset');
serviceAsset.addQuery('u_service',service_sys_id);
serviceAsset.addNotNullQuery('u_parent');
serviceAsset.query();
gs.log(serviceAsset.getEncodedQuery());
```

This prints the following in the logs

> u_service=305baa6fdb17d0d44bb6e126059619e1^u_parent!=NULL^sys_idNotValidnull^ORsys_idNotValidnull

What does `sys_idNotValidnull` mean and why is it getting added as an OR condition?

I've a "Query" Business Rule on the table but that code doesn't seem to be referencing the above.

#### Business Rule code

```
(function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) {  
    
    var serviceassetquery;
    serviceassetquery = current.addEncodedQuery("u_sourcesystem!=Wholesale^ORu_sourcesystem=NULL");
    
})(current, previous);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the

```
sys_idNotValidnull^ORsys_idNotValidnull
```

part was being added by the Business Rule. And the reason for `sys_idNotValidnull` presence was because the column `u_sourcesystem` was NOT present on the table `u_service_asset`

Duh! It was an invalid column after all that caused all the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `sys_idNotValidnull` means **"referred sys_id is not exist"**.

The easiest and best way to get an encoded query as follows:

1. Navigate to the table.
2. Build filter and run
3. Right-click on the bread crumb (You will see copy query option that will give **proper encoded query**, Please refer to the screenshot attached)

**Example of copied query:** "`active=true^state!=10^ORstate=^sys_idISNOTEMPTY`"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this. Issue has been found, will put it up as an answer in case someone else stumbles upon a similar scenario.

Comment: Can you please add your answer? I am excited to know.